# Jquery index error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).index(...).remove is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use https://api.jquery.com/index/ property in jquery but when when I try to write this code it shows me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).index(...).remove is not a function.

I try to use `index()` in js and everything worked well but I need to write the same code in jquery. Here is what the code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.chkhka194i')[index2].remove();
```

and what I've tried in jquery:

```
$('.chkhka194i').index(index2).remove();
```

Comment: Where is your HTML ? What are trying to remove! Provide a minimal example of your work. Read here how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why you need html? i only want to resolve jquery problem

Comment: No worries! Good luck with the getting a solution. Thank you.

Comment: what is the type of `index2`? note, jquery's `.index()` does not accept a numeric index, but a Selector or Element to search for and **returns** a numeric index. that is probably why you get "remove is not a function". this is all written in the link you provided.

Comment: you are looking for [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) not `index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery `.index()` function always returns an integer, so there's no `.remove()` function available (on integer).

> ```
> https://api.jquery.com/index/
> ```
>
> "the return value is an integer"

In this case you can use the `.eq()` function to get the element at that position:

```
$('.chkhka194i').eq(index2).remove();
```

to call [jquery remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Alternatively you can use `[index2]` to get a DOM node (rather than a jquery object) and use vanilla javascript methods (that confusingly have the same name but are different methods)

```
$('.chkhka194i')[index2].remove();
```

which will use [vanilla javascript remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)